# app not running in ipad

Tags: ipad, nsfilemanager

HI guys,

my app works fine in the simulator,
(Im trying to upload to a jail broken ipad, with expired profile, was loading compiled apps fine before xcode 3.2.5, I got some problems to upload, but now, I think the issues are fixed)

but now, the app breaks up when loading, I get this error (and some warnings), but first  to fix this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c550'

the line that it refers is>

> - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
>     return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
>     }

Is that line compatible with iOS 3.2.2 (7B500)??, is that the problem?
or what could be??

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is only available in iOS 4 or later.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Availability
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.